# How to send value in javascript to django

Tags: javascript, django

I try to get value in django from javascript but it's none value in some variable.

template.html

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        first();
        $('#btnAdd').click(first);
    });
    var choices = ["one", "two", "three"];

    function first() {
        var id = $('#cover div').length + 1; 
        var wrapper = $("<div id=\"field" + id + "\" class='row info'><p></p>");
        var category = "";
        category = "<div class='col-md-2'><select class='form-control' name=\"category" + id + "\">";
        for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i = i + 1) {
            category += "<option value='" + choices[i] + "'>" + choices[i] + "</option>";
        }
        category += "</select></div>";
        var product = $("<div class='col-md-5'><input type='text' id='tags' name=\"product" + id + "\" class='form-control' size=40 placeholder='ชื่อสินค้า' required/></div>"); // สร้าง input
        wrapper.append(category, product);
        $('#cover').append(wrapper);
        $(wrapper).find("input[name^='product']").autocomplete({
            source: "/autocomplete_product?category",
            minLength: 2,
        });
    }
```

views.py

```
    product = request.GET['term']
    category = request.GET['category']
```

I try to print request.GET, it show category and term variable. The term variable is normal (there is value) but category is null. I have question how to I send category to django.

Comment: Have you looked into the Network Tab of the browser DevTools to check, what is submitted?
I'd suspect, that `name=\"category" + id + "\"` is causing it to be `category2` (instead of `category`).

Answer (score 0):

```
category = "<div class='col-md-2'><select class='form-control' name=category>";
```

try this.

Comment: Your post may answer this question but code only post is considered as low quality in this community. Please try to add more explaination.